# How to access fsevents to get the file system events?

Tags: events, macos, fsevents

Though i had read the fsevents article provided by apple developer site, i m having issues in receiving the events. I need some samples to fetch events.

Need some samples.
Thanks in advance.

rgds,

herby

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the middle of solving this and MacFSEvents looks promising (that is, if you're OK with using Python).